# SSIS append rows with new constraints

Tags: ssis

There are two databases with similar schema, DB_1 and DB_2 both databases have their own data with auto generated primary keys. **I want to insert DB_2 data into DB_1, to make one database**. My Problem is DB_2 primary keys may exists in DB_1, so i want to append DB_2 rows with new primary key, So how can i do this through **SSIS**.
Please guide me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `control flow`, create a `data flow task`.  In the `data flow task`, add the following items:

- Data Source: its connection manager should point to DB_2.
- Data Destination: its connection manager should point to DB_1.

Make sure the data flow path connects the source and destination.  In the destination, make sure all of the source columns are mapped to the destination columns except for the `PrimaryKey` column.  Since the primary keys are auto generated, the database creates the new primary keys upon inserting the data.

Comment: thanks @David, it is very helpful, But kindly tell me about foreign keys in a table. How can we maintain **track of foreign keys**?

Comment: @nasir, I don't quite know what you mean by maintain track of them.  If you would like to find a foreign key as part of your data flow, you can add a look up component between the source and destination in the data flow task to look for the key in another table.  Another option is to load the data into a temporary table and use sql to insert the data (while joining to your foreign tables to get the foreign keys) into the destination tables.